# Google Maps Engine API - KML Layers Obstructing New Markers Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I am currently building out a small widget that allows someone to see a kml heat map of the united states population density then select an area on that map and drop a market on to that location. The user then enters a number and that creates a mile radius to show the user how much area they cover.

My problem is that I have 63 .kml files for just one state in the US. I know I can remove the xml `<name>` and `<description>` to prevent the name from popping up when clicked, but I can't see that being practical with that many .kml files.

Is there a programmatic solution or API solution to prevent just the kml layers from being clickable?

```js
   var citymap = {};

   citymap['chicago'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
     value: 2714856
   };
   citymap['newyork'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
     value: 8405837
   };
   citymap['losangeles'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
     value: 3857799
   };
   citymap['vancouver'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1),
     value: 603502
   };

   var cityCircle;

   function initialize() {
     // Create the map.
     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 8,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.7361, -92.3311),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     };

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);

     // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
     // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
     for (var city in citymap) {
       var populationOptions = {
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
         strokeWeight: 2,
         fillColor: '#FF0000',
         fillOpacity: 0.35,
         map: map,
         center: citymap[city].center,
         radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].value) * 100
       };
       // Add the circle for this city to the map.
       cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
     }

     var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
       url: 'http://www.census.gov/main/kml/countysubs_z6/AR/05003.xml'
     });
     ctaLayer.setMap(map);

     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
       placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
     });
   }

   function placeMarker(position, map) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       map: map
     });
     map.panTo(position);
   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Discretionary note: Google API does not work well with Stack Overflow's code snippet's widget.

Comment: Seems like it is the signed_in=true that causing the issues with SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) clickable option to false

> clickable boolean If true, the layer receives mouse events. Default value is true.

```js
var citymap = {};

   citymap['chicago'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
     value: 2714856
   };
   citymap['newyork'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
     value: 8405837
   };
   citymap['losangeles'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
     value: 3857799
   };
   citymap['vancouver'] = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1),
     value: 603502
   };

   var cityCircle;

   function initialize() {
     // Create the map.
     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 8,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.7361, -92.3311),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     };

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);

     // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
     // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
     for (var city in citymap) {
       var populationOptions = {
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
         strokeWeight: 2,
         fillColor: '#FF0000',
         fillOpacity: 0.35,
         map: map,
         center: citymap[city].center,
         radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].value) * 100
       };
       // Add the circle for this city to the map.
       cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
     }

     var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
       url: 'http://www.census.gov/main/kml/countysubs_z6/AR/05003.xml',
       clickable: false
     });
     ctaLayer.setMap(map);

     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
       placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
     });
   }

   function placeMarker(position, map) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       map: map
     });
     map.panTo(position);
   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```